# Auto code format does not keep line break

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Recently I just updated my android studio. I noticed that when I try to format my code, it ended up like the image below?
[image: ImageFormat]
Can we make it like this instead:

```
openCameraObservable
            .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({}, {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin -> Wrapping and Braces -> Chained Function Calls

Set it to "Wrap if long" or "Wrap always"

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I prefer the option `chop down if long` to `wrap always`.